# React problem with canvas - misscalculate position of mouse

Tags: javascript, reactjs, canvas

I try to build mini paint in browser with using typescript + styled-components + react, however Canvas calculates position of mouse wrongly when I try to draw something. Thing is that it happens only when I use canvas which is located inside CanvasContainer, If I just write tag <canvas ... /> inside ImageEditor then position is counted correctly. Does anyone has any idea why does it happen and how to fix it? As I don't really understand this behaviour.

```
export default function ImageEditorContainer() {
  const CANVAS_REF = useRef<any>(null);

  const isDrawing = useRef(false);


  function startDrawing(event: MouseEvent) {
    isDrawing.current = true;
    const canvas = CANVAS_REF.current;
    const context = canvas.getContext('2d');
    console.log('STARt');
    context.beginPath();
    context.moveTo(event.clientX - canvas.offsetLeft, event.clientY - canvas.offsetTop);
    event.preventDefault();
  }

  function draw(event: MouseEvent) {
    if (isDrawing.current) {
      const canvas = CANVAS_REF.current;
      const context = canvas.getContext('2d');
      console.log('Draw');

      context.lineTo(event.clientX - canvas.offsetLeft, event.clientY - canvas.offsetTop);
      context.strokeStyle = 'black';
      context.lineWidth = '3px';
      context.lineCap = 'round';
      context.lineJoin = 'round';
      context.stroke();
    }
    event.preventDefault();
  }

  function stopDrawing(event: MouseEvent) {
    if (isDrawing.current) {
      const canvas = CANVAS_REF.current;
      const context = canvas.getContext('2d');
      console.log('STOP');

      context.stroke();
      context.closePath();
      isDrawing.current = false;
    }
    event.preventDefault();
  }

  useEffect(() => {
      const canvas = CANVAS_REF.current;
      if (canvas) {
        canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', startDrawing);
        canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', draw);
        canvas.addEventListener('mouseup', stopDrawing);
        canvas.addEventListener('mouseout', stopDrawing);
      }
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      ....

      <CanvasContainer CANVAS_REF={CANVAS_REF} ... />
    </>
  );
}


export default function CanvasContainer({ ...restProps }: TCanvasContent) {
  return (
    <Canvas.Container>
      <Canvas.Content {...restProps} />
    </Canvas.Container>
  );
}


export default function Canvas({ children }: TCanvas) {
  return { children };
}

Canvas.Content = function CanvasContent({ CANVAS_REF, ...restProps }: TCanvasContent) {
  return <Content ref={CANVAS_REF} {...restProps} />;
};
```

[image]

https://codesandbox.io/s/dank-dust-vo4lh?file=/src/CanvasContainer.js

Comment: are you able to provide a running example in JSFiddle? https://jsfiddle.net/s1xh6g0d/

Comment: Then I will solve this

Comment: @ru4ert hello, I added link to sandbox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it worked.

https://codesandbox.io/s/peaceful-jepsen-wh913?file=/src/App.js

The "Style" of the canvas was wrong.

Comment: it works! I would never guess that it was problem with styles, wonder why styled components counted it wrongly, anyway thanks you are my hero!